# Flutter Background_fetch lib does not run after terminating app

Tags: android, flutter, background-fetch

I'm trying to implement push notifications type function to remind user some events.
I want my App to get content from server once or twice in a day.

I'm trying to use [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) library. Problem is that when app is terminated Job does not get called even tho I have `stopOnTerminate: false,` setted. Here is my configure code:

```
var config = BackgroundFetchConfig(
  minimumFetchInterval: 15,
  forceAlarmManager: false,
  stopOnTerminate: false,
  startOnBoot: true,
  enableHeadless: true,
  requiresBatteryNotLow: false,
  requiresCharging: false,
  requiresStorageNotLow: false,
  requiresDeviceIdle: false,
  requiredNetworkType: NetworkType.ANY,

);

BackgroundFetch.configure(config, (String taskId) async {
  print("[BackgroundFetch] Event received $taskId");

  print("my code is here");

  BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
}).then((int status) {
  print('[BackgroundFetch] configure success: $status');

}).catchError((e) {
  print('[BackgroundFetch] configure ERROR: $e');
});
```

My MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity implements PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback{

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BackgroundFetchPlugin.setPluginRegistrant(this);
}


@Override
public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith((FlutterEngine) registry);
}
}
```

I also added `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` and `tools:replace="android:label"` in manifest. 
 
I'm simulating job with this command: `adb shell cmd jobscheduler run -f com.mycompany.appname 999` .
When app is active or it's in foreground, my function gets called by the command over and over again (no problem, works good), but when I terminate my app the command give me this message: `Could not find job 999 in package com.mycompany.appname / user 0`, 
sometimes it give me `Running job [FORCED]` only once, but actually my function is not called, and on another run it tells me there is no job.

I've heard that this does not work in debug mode, so I run my app with `flutter run --release`. Well with no success.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work when you run the project from the terminal with `flutter run`.
Look at [this bug report](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101912).